# Number in PHP form being saved as a random number in mySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have a form to add/edit a record in a mysql database.
However when entering a phone number, such as '07854301812', '2147483647' is saved in the database.
I have echoed out the $number variable, and this is the correct value, so something is going wrong when storing in the database.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `customer` SET `f_name` = '$fname',`l_name` = '$lname',`email` = '$email',`number` = '$number' WHERE `c_id` = '$id'");
```

and this is my sql DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    c_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    f_name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    l_name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    number      INTEGER,
    date_joined DATE NOT NULL CHECK (date_added <= now())
);
```

Comment: tried using big integer?

Answer (score 1):

Your number is larger than the largest integer you can store. Given your numbers start with a `0` that'll get truncated if you switch to using a `BIGINT`, you should probably just store them as a `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, looks like the '2147483647' is the max positive value for an INT.

Some info on integer types (and sizes): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

You can quickly change the schema to use a larger number like the following:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Customer MODIFY number BIGINT;
```

Some more info on the Alter syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

So long as you go from a smaller number to larger number you won't lose any information in your table.

You should be able to test pretty quickly with that and see if it works.